# JavaFX: How to ask for user input before a GUI is displayed

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

I'm having a little bit of trouble with JavaFX in Netbeans 7.3.1. I'm attempting to make a game that rolls a die. The program is supposed to ask the user if the die is fair or not, along with other information (such as number of sides) to initialize a die to roll. When the roll button is clicked, it will roll the die.

My issue is that since JavaFX ignores the main program when it launches a GUI, I'm not sure where (or how) to ask the user for this information before the GUI loads.

```
public class DiceGame extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Roll Die!");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            // 
            // code for rolling a die goes here.
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Dice Game");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //ask user for n value to initialize a die object before the javafx ui is launched.

    System.out.println("Is your die loaded or fair? *Input 1 for fair and 2 for loaded* ");

    Scanner fair_or_loaded = new Scanner(System.in); //Determines fair or loaded die.
    int input = fair_or_loaded.nextInt();

    if (input == 1) {
        System.out.println("Input an N value for a fair die: ");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in); //Created a fair die.
        int n = user_input.nextInt();
        Die D1 = new Die(n); //User created die.

    } else { //Loaded die is created. Need Scanner for loadedSide and LoadFactor.
        System.out.println("Input an N value for a loaded die: ");
        Scanner loaded_n_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int loaded_n = loaded_n_input.nextInt(); //loaded n value created

        System.out.println("Input a side to be loaded: ");
        Scanner user_side = new Scanner(System.in);
        int side_loaded = user_side.nextInt(); //loaded side created

        System.out.println("Input a load factor: ");
        Scanner user_load = new Scanner(System.in);
        int factor_load = user_load.nextInt(); //load factor created

        LoadedDie DL = new LoadedDie(loaded_n, side_loaded, factor_load); //Loaded die is created.
    }

     launch(args);  
  }
}
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment in that code, JavaFX applications, when launched properly, don't use the `main()` method as traditional Java applications do - they create an instance of the default application class and call its start method.

So if you want this code to execute before the GUI is shown, you'll have to call it at the beginning of the start method. Preferably, put the corresponding code in a separate method then just call that method before you start building your UI.